# Generate list of pairs

Tags: c++

I have *string[]* containing names (let's say just football teams, it doesn't matter).

I need to **generate random pairs of these names**, but i have no idea how to do it.

Let's say *string[]* looks like this:

```
string[] s = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"}
```

and i need to generate random combinations of these so output will be like this

```
Name1 ---
         |-----
Name3 ---      |
               |--
Name4 ---      |
         |-----
Name2 ---
```

It doesn't matter if output will be like this, or less graphical, it's just illustrational.
Only **thing i need is** 
`string[][] = {{"Name1","Name3"}{"Name4", "Name2"}`

Comment: what have you tried? If you really need a hint, try randomly generating numbers.....

Comment: If you want help with your homework, you need to show a bit of effort here.  Break the problem down into tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ makes doing things like this easier than you may imagine. You can use slightly more advanced C++ constructs to hold your list of names, shuffle it, and cut it into pairs. First, in C++, it's generally considered good practice to use std::vector's instead of regular arrays. The C++ vector class creates a dynamic array for you, managing all memory so you don't have to. If you are really set on using a std::string[] that's fine too, just a bit harder to negotiate. To solve your problem using vectors, I created a vector of strings like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"};
```

What you can do is use a C++ built in algorithm called std::random_shuffle to shuffle the vector into something like this:

```
{"name2","name3","name1","name4"}
```

or any other random permutation of the vector. Then you can simply loop over the vector, pairing up every two values. In C++, you can use the std::pair data structure, which contains two values of type T, in your case std::string. You can make pairs of these, then push them onto a vector of pairs instead of storing your final result in a 2d array.

If you don't want to do all of this C++ stuff, you can simply use arrays and follow the same format. Shuffle your array, loop over your array, put the pairs of names into your 2d array.

If you want to use more C++ related data structures and algorithms, check out these pages:

Vector:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Pair:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

random_shuffle:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/